# New-AzureStorageContext: Endpoint vs Environment

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

For the New-AzureStorageContext cmdlet, assuming I know the value for both, what are the differences between the Endpoint and Environment parameters?

For example, let's say I want a new a new storage context named `foo` within the Azure China cloud, so the environment is `AzureChinaCloud` and the endpoint would be `foo.core.chinacloudapi.cn` I can pass either of those in as a parameter to the cmdlet, although it appears from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontext?view=azurermps-6.8.0) that they are mutually exclusive.

What would functionally be different between passing one or the other? If I pass Environment, does the created storage context not have an endpoint? If it does have an endpoint, is it not set to `foo.core.chinacloudapi.cn`? If I pass the Endpoint, does the context not get set to `AzureChinaCloud`? Is it even possible not to have one or the other?

Furthermore, the returned [AzureStorageContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.storage.azurestoragecontext?view=azurerm-ps) has a number of properties related to endpoint: `BlobEndPoint`, `EndPointSuffix`, `FileEndPoint`, `QueueEndPoint`, and `TableEndPoint`. Which of these properties should be set when passing either Environment or Endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what are the differences between the Endpoint and Environment parameters?

`Endpoint`: it contains the storage account name and the azure environment, if `AzureCloud`, it will be `storagename.core.windows.net`, if `AzureChinaCloud`, it will be `storagename.core.chinacloudapi.cn` like you mentioned, it belongs to `Optional Parameters`.

`Environment`: it just specify the environment, not contain the storage account name.

> If I pass Environment, does the created storage context not have an endpoint? If it does have an endpoint, is it not set to foo.core.chinacloudapi.cn? If I pass the Endpoint, does the context not get set to AzureChinaCloud?

I think you dont need to use both of them, if you pass the account name and environment, the context will have the endpoint, also, if you pass the endpoint, it will have the environment.

> Is it even possible not to have one or the other?

Of course, you could use other parameters to create the context, e.g. you could just use `StorageAccountName` and `StorageAccountKey` to create the context, you could find it in the doc you mentioned.

> Which of these properties should be set when passing either Environment or Endpoint?

The four properties are all decided by the endpoint, if you pass the endpoint, I think you dont need to set them. e.g. If the endpoint is `storagename.core.windows.net`, the `BlobEndPoint` will be `storagename.blob.core.windows.net`.

**Update:**

> what are the differences between the Endpoint and Environment parameters?

Different environments decide different endpoints, you could check it by the command: [`Get-AzureRmEnvironment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/get-azurermenvironment?view=azurermps-6.8.0). if `AzureCloud`, it will be `core.windows.net`, if `AzureChinaCloud`, it will be `core.chinacloudapi.cn`

AzureCloud:

[image]

AzureChinaCloud:

[image]

> If I pass Environment, does the created storage context not have an endpoint? If it does have an endpoint, is it not set to foo.core.chinacloudapi.cn? If I pass the Endpoint, does the context not get set to AzureChinaCloud?

You could just use one of them, refer to the screenshot, **note:** actually the `Endpoint` means `EndPointSuffix`, you could find it in my test result. So we should pass e.g. `-Endpoint "core.windows.net"` instead of `-Endpoint "storagename.core.windows.net"`. If we pass `-Endpoint "storagename.core.windows.net"`, it will be incorrect, the `EndPointSuffix` will be `storagename.core.windows.net` in the result.

[image]

[image]

Incorrect result:

[image]

> Which of these properties should be set when passing either Environment or Endpoint?

In the above screenshots, I dont pass any of these four endpoints, but you could find the result will have all of them. Also you dont need to pass `EndPointSuffix`, it equals `EndPoint`.

Comment: @fepiv I did some test, you could refer to my update.

Comment: From your answer, it looks like if I know the value for both Endpoint and Environment, passing either value effectively produces equivalent AzureStorageContexts. BTW, thanks for the tips on EndpointSuffix. This is very unclear from the the MS docs.